# Missing linux kernel header file

Tags: c, regex, linux, include, kernel

I'm currently developing a kernel module which should make use of regex to filter some input.

Since the standard user-mode library regex.h should not be used in kernel-mode programs, I've decided to have a look at the regex functionality of **trace.h** from the kernel [see here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/trace/trace.h#L1433).

The implementation was't quite a problem but when I was trying to include the header file my IDE displayed an error that it could not find any header with the name **trace.h** in the respective folder. So I've search the `/usr/src/` directory for trace.h but couldn't find in neither `linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64/` nor `linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/`

I'm developing on Debian 9 with kernel version 4.9.0-3. Does anyone have me a clue how to include this header file?

Comment: What does `locate trace.h` or `find / -name trace.h ` tell you? Did you install the right development packages?like `linux-headers-generic` for your kernel version, e.g.?

Comment: Check if the `linux-headers` package is installed on your machine `dpkg -l |grep linux-headers` . If the package is not installed, run `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I already tried this. Locate couldn't find it as well and find found some trace.h files but not the expected.

Comment: @RoseHosting: I've installed the newst version "linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 is already the newest version (4.9.30-2+deb9u5).
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because path to the header is `trace/trace.h`, the header cannot be used by kernel
modules - it is **internal** for trace utility. This is not surprising that the header is absent in `linux-headers` package - that package is intended for build kernel modules.